# Codedeploy-agent keeps more revisions than the number specified in config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

On my AWS instance, I have set `max_revisions` in `/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml` to 1 and restarted the service with `sudo service codedeploy-agent restart`.

However, under `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/` I still found 4 copies.

Is there any step I missed to restrict the number of copies kept by codedeploy-agent?

Comment: Have you done a deploy after making the change?

Comment: @RodrigoM not yet. Will the deletion of redundant copies happen at the time? It might take a few more days for our team to do the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `max_revisions` in the CodeDeploy agent configuration, there are two steps that need to happen before old copies get cleaned up.

1. Restart the agent (which you've done)
2. Deploy a new revision

Since you haven't done a deployment yet, the old revisions are still hanging around. Once you deploy a new revision, you should see the change.